# Windows file alert

Tags: windows, powershell

Need idea.
A program is designed to play 4 wav files to alert 4 different categories. I want to know which file is played so I can use arduino to turn on different colour led for visual alarm. This is on windows 10.
Procmon can show files that are in use but probably can’t make it to alert.
Do you have any idea?
Thanks

Comment: I can think of several ways to get this information, but I'd be interested to see how you've approached the problem. Please post some sample code of what you've tried thus far. Also, welcome to StackOverflow!

Comment: Oh, sorry to disappoint, I haven’t written any code yet as I can’t think of any ways to do it and thus the post. Once I figure out how to proceed I’ll sure show some code. Thank you.

Comment: Anyone can help ?